# How do I do this select statement?

Tags: mysql

Tables and Columns are Below

```
Bikers(BikerName, Country, Age, Category, World_Cup_Wins, 

World_Championship_Wins, Brand, Bike)

BikerMeetUp(BikerName, Date, Location)

BikeShopInfo(BikeShopName, Telephone_Number, Address, Website)

Brands(BrandName, Website, Model)

Bikes(Model, Price, Weight, Colour, Rating, State)

BikeTyre(Model, Tyre_Model, Size)

BikeForks(Model, Fork_Model, Travel)

BikeBrandSellStock(Model, Size, BrandStock)

BikeShopSellBike(BikeShopName, Model, Size, BikeShopStock)
```

I want to select the bike with the most total stock available i.e. stock from brand + stock from bike shop? How do I do this? This is what I have so far and it is not executing.

```
Select model, price, rating, state, brands.brandname, brands.website, 
bikebrandsellstock.size, bikebrandsellstock.brandstock, bikeshopsellbike.bikeshopname, bikeshopsellbike.size, bikeshopsellbike.bikeshopstock 
from bikes 
INNER JOIN brands ON bikes.model = brands.model 
INNER JOIN bikebrandsellstock ON bikes.model = bikebrandsellstock.model 
INNER JOIN bikeshopsellbike ON bikes.model = bikeshopsellbike.model 
WHERE SUM(bikebrandsellstock.stock+bikeshopsellbike.stock) 
IN (SELECT MAX(SUM(bikebrandsellstock.stock+bikeshopsellbike.stock)))
```

Comment: Omer, your edit was a regression and it was undone. You wrecked the query formatting that coldspeed put in

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're overthinking it:

```
SELECT * 

FROM 
 bikebrandsellstock b 
 INNER JOIN 
 bikeshopsellbike s 
 ON s.model = b.model and s.size = s.size

ORDER BY b.brandstock + s.bikeshopstock DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax in `(SELECT MAX(SUM(bikebrandsellstock.stock+bikeshopsellbike.stock)))` is incorrect, you are missing a `FROM` statement.

Comment: It seems that JC is expecting the subquery to work out because it uses table aliases from the parent query. Your answer may benefit from some explanation as to why this doesn't work in this context?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT model
     , SUM(stock) total
  FROM
     ( SELECT Model, BrandStock stock FROM BikeBrandSellStock
        UNION
       SELECT Model, BikeShopStock FROM BikeShopSellBike
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY model
 ORDER 
    BY total DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
```

This solution does not account for ties.